# Two possible programming patterns, which one is more appropriate?

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns, remote-server, template-specialization

I'm working on a new .Net library which needs to simplify the interface to our server. I like LINQ and my current design is very much influenced by it.

Currently I know of two possible programming patterns for the task but I cannot decide which one is cleaner. In C++ I would use template specialization but I cannot use that in C#.

I could use one generic base interface and then specify derived interfaces which add some special methods and override (hide) some derived methods:

```
interface ISelection<out T> {
    ISelection<T> Skip(int n);
    ISelection<T> Method2();
    ISelection<T> Method3();
    ISelection<T> Method4();

    ISelection<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector);
    IDateTimeSelection Select(Func<T, DateTime> selector);

    IResult<T> Submit();
}

interface IDateTimeSelection : ISelection<DateTime> {
    new IDateTimeSelection Skip(int n);
    new IDateTimeSelection Method2();
    new IDateTimeSelection Method3();
    new IDateTimeSelection Method4();

    IDateTimeSelection SpecialMethod();
}
```

I'm also considering the *[curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)* to avoid the overriding (hiding) of derived methods.

```
interface IBaseSelection<out Selection, out T> where Selection : IBaseSelection<Selection, T> {
    Selection Skip(int n);
    Selection Method2();
    Selection Method3();
    Selection Method4();

    ISelection<TResult> Select<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> selector);
    IDateTimeSelection Select(Func<T, DateTime> selector);

    IResult<T> Submit();
}

interface ISelection<out T> : IBaseSelection<ISelection<T>, T> {
}

interface IDateTimeSelection : IBaseSelection<IDateTimeSelection, DateTime> {
    IDateTimeSelection SpecialMethod();
}
```

At the end I need to be able to do the following:

```
ISelection<Dataset> datasets = ...
var result = datasets
    .Select(dataset => dataset.Date)
    .Skip(5)
    .SpecialMethod()
    .Submit();
```

I hope you can show me which approach I should use or even convince me to use a better way.

PS: I cannot use extension methods as a workaround for template specialization.

Comment: In your first example, why are you creating a `IDateTimeSelection` interface? Isn't it enough for a type to implement `ISelection<DateTime>`?

Comment: Certain selections (e.g. `IDateTimeSelection`) need some extra methods.

Comment: Then why are you creating `new` methods with a `IDateTimeSelection` type? why not just add the specific methods? 
if `IDateTimeSelection` inherits `ISelection<DateTime>` then the user can return an `IDateTimeSelection`

Comment: Why is `ISelection<T>` returning a `IDateTimeSelection`?

Comment: I added a small use case to my question which should demonstrate why/when `ISelection<T>` returns `IDateTimeSelection`

Comment: You are coupling an inherited type to its base. I wouldn't do that

Comment: In your sample use case, the `Select()` method looks like it would be implemented as a service locator. Wouldn't it be easier to instead extend your `Dataset` class with a `Dates` property of type `IDateTimeSelection`?

Comment: Example: `Datasets.Dates.Skip(5).SpecialMethod().Submit();`
where `Dates : IDateTimeSelection`.

Comment: I cannot incorporate Dates into `ISelection` because that interface needs to be able to work with many different tables which have different kind of datasets.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably the same what G.Y. meant, but I will extend it, to show the solution for your case.

```
public interface ISelection<out T>
    where T : ISelection<T>
{
    T Skip(int n);
    T Method2();
    T Method3();
}

public interface IDateTimeSelection<out T> : ISelection<T>
    where T : IDateTimeSelection<T>
{
    T SpecialMethod();
}

public class Implementation : IDateTimeSelection<Implementation>
{
    public Implementation Skip(int n)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Implementation Method2()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Implementation Method3()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public Implementation SpecialMethod()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

You can do this in the end:

```
        var impl = new Implementation2();
        impl.Skip(2).Method2().Method3().SpecialMethod().Method2();
```

If I understand it properly, this is how CRTP is implemented in C#. Your example of CRTP is quite complex, any reasons for that?

Comment: Why not use `IDateTimeSelection<out T> : ISelection<DateTime>` ot at least `where T is DateTime`?

Comment: Because T is not DateTime but rather ISelection<DateTime> or any of it's children. In the Implementation class T is Implementation. But I agree where keyword can be put here. Even should be

Comment: Thank you for your interest, unfortunately I cannot see how your example would help me. I added a small use case at the end of my question.

Comment: I probably do not fully understand your question. If the problem is in making your operations chain and support inheritance - this is the way it can be done. See my edit as an example of using it. Or the problem is in being able to call Select on ISelection and receive IDateTimeSelection?

Comment: @user667967 Ok, sorry for the confusion, now I see the question you had. After your edits for the question the CRTP option looks correct. These Select methods add a lot of mess there and it is really hard to figure out what is all about here, but probably you cannot make it better, at least I have no idea how to do that. Still I would vote for CRTP option, as overriding all the stuff each time (option 1) looks too workload for me. I tried that once and still finished with CRTP. If your hierarchy is not small - you should go with CRTP. If it is very small - 1st option may be a choice then

Answer (score 2):

I have used the "curiously recurring template pattern" a lot in the past few weeks, to enable method chaining.

However I happened to notice that this has a caveat: Each of your special class inherits a different interface. Although they are all defined by the same source code, the differences in generic type arguments will in fact make them different types. This can incur issues if you want to put differently-typed ISelection-s into one collection, for example.

Except if you make `<T>` a `<out T>`. This in turn implies that you can only "output", that is, return `T`-typed objects but not take them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Its a tough choice. Think about the future. What could be expected changes, new functionality? And what impact it would make to both the implementations. Think about Open-Closed principle, loose coupling/high cohesion.

You don't want to end up in a situation where the base interface has 10 functions, some implementations ONLY implement only a small subset and throw NotDefined exception for the rest.

First approach is a bit more loosely coupled. By defining a base selection class there's a sort of constraint for all implementing classes to use the base methods. I would be very careful when using the 2nd approach.

I would suggest prototyping both the approaches for a small number of interfaces and see how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try that as your prototype and evolve from it?

```
    public interface ISelection<out T>
    {
        T Skip(int n);
        T Method2();
        T Method3();
        T Method4();
        T SpecialMethod();
    }
```

Comment: That implementation would make him break the contract everytime he wants to add a new method and would cause `ISelection` to become a huge interface eventually

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov what contract?? I don't see any contract definition in his question and I don't see WCF in the tags.

Comment: Interface == contract. If i use his 3rd party library and implement `ISelection<T>`, when he ships the next version he adds a new method to the interface, he is breaking the "contract" with me and causing my application to break.

Comment: I can only use `SpecialMethod()` with `IDateTimeSelection` and I want to avoid runtime exceptions.

Comment: well.. in that case - seems that archeg evolved it correctly in his answer.